# Can't create and find Java Web Application on Avalible Plugins. NetBeans 8.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, plugins, netbeans-8.1

I installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 hier https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html NetBeans 8.1 for Java EE. But I can't create Web Application.

tried to install it on Avalible Plugins, but I can't find it!!

Answer (score 0):

Very strange behaviour. You cold try to create maven WebApp project.

File -> New Project -> Categories: Maven -> Projects: Web Application